# How to list the path of files inside Hdfs directory and subdirectory?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

Could not figure out a way to list all files in directory and subdirectories.

Here is the code that I'm using which lists files in a specific directory but files if there is a subdorectory inside:

```
val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://servername/"), conf)
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("path/to/folder/"))
status.foreach { x => println(x.getPath.toString()) }
```

the above code lists all the files inside the directory but I need it to be recursive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go for a recursion whenever you discover a new folder:

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())

def listFileNames(hdfsPath: String): List[String] = {

  hdfs
    .listStatus(new Path(hdfsPath))
    .flatMap { status =>
      // If it's a file:
      if (status.isFile)
        List(hdfsPath + "/" + status.getPath.getName)
      // If it's a dir and we're in a recursive option:
      else
        listFileNames(hdfsPath + "/" + status.getPath.getName)
    }
    .toList
    .sorted
}
```

Comment: what is the use of sorted here ?

Comment: You can absolutely remove it, specially when working on high number of files. I usually like having the list sorted whenever I print or unit test things.

Comment: is there a way to filter for specific file extensions ? say only '.xml'

Comment: You could apply a filter on the resulting list of paths: `.filter(_.endsWith(".xml"))` or directly within the function by returning `Nil` (`List()`) when `status.getPath.getName.endsWith(".xml")`

Comment: Thanks - cloud not figure out how to filter to 2 or more file types - xml and pdf ?

Comment: Same: `.filter(p => p.endsWith(".xml") || p.endsWith(".pdf"))`. Might want to ask additional questions as new questions though.