# list files recursively and filter by extension

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to recursively go through a given directory and all it's subdirectories, and list all the files that end with .json.  Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52446246/2751573), I've got the recursive bit working.  Now I'm trying to figure out the filtering part.

Here's my current attempt:

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem,Path, PathFilter}
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

    val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

    def listJsonFiles(hdfsPath: String): List[String] = {
      fs
        .listStatus(new Path(hdfsPath)).filter(_.getPath.getName.endsWith(".json"))
        //.listStatus(new Path(hdfsPath))
        .flatMap { obj =>
          if (obj.isFile)
            List(hdfsPath + "/" + obj.getPath.getName)
          // If it's a dir and we're in a recursive option:
          else
            listJsonFiles(hdfsPath + "/" + obj.getPath.getName)
        }
        .toList
    }
    val files = listJsonFiles("/path/to/some/stuff")
```

That returns an empty list. If I use the listStatus line without the filter, it returns a list of all the files in the path I pass in, including all the *.json files. So I know they exist, I can just can't get the filter working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the filter is applied first that filters out subdirectory. Move the filter down to flatMap.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

def listJsonFiles(hdfsPath: String): List[String] = {
  fs
    .listStatus(new Path(hdfsPath))
    //.listStatus(new Path(hdfsPath))
    .flatMap { obj =>
      if (obj.isDirectory) listJsonFiles(obj.getPath.toString)
      else if(obj.getPath.getName.endsWith(".json")) List(obj.getPath.toString)
      else Nil
    }
    .toList
}
val files = listJsonFiles("/var/tmp/stuff")
files.foreach(println)
```

There is native method on FileSystem to recursively scan HDFS directory.

`FileSystem.listFiles` takes an argument to do recursive search and return `RemoteIteator` which we can use to filter the desired files. This also guards JVM running from OOO.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, RemoteIterator}

val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

// implicit for converting remote Iterator to scala iterator
implicit def  remoteIteratorToIterator[A](ri: RemoteIterator[A]): Iterator[A] = new Iterator[A] {
  override def hasNext: Boolean = ri.hasNext

  override def next(): A = ri.next()
}

def listJsonFiles(hdfsPath: String): List[String] = {
  fs
    .listFiles(new Path(hdfsPath), true)
    .map(_.getPath.toString)
    .filter(_.endsWith(".json"))
    .toList
}
val files = listJsonFiles("/var/tmp/stuff")
files.foreach(println)
```

Input directory

```
$ tree stuff/
stuff/
├── dir1
│   ├── dir1.json
│   └── dir2
│       └── dir2.json
└── stuff.json

2 directories, 3 files
```

Output

```
file:/var/tmp/stuff/stuff.json
file:/var/tmp/stuff/dir1/dir2/dir2.json
file:/var/tmp/stuff/dir1/dir1.json
```